# MathML Typographical Error on Firefox 17 on GNU/Linux

Tags: typography, mathml

Apparently, I cannot post images because I was deemed not 1337 enough unless I get 10 points of reputation, so let me do my best to describe the problem.

Here is the markup that I am trying to render. Pay no attention to the content, because I just took an arbitrary paper from ArXiv for reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Example Paper</title>
    <style>
      * { 
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      } body {
        width: 616px;
        /*background: url(background.png) center top repeat-y #fff;*/
        margin: 0 auto;
      } h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
        line-height: 22px;
        margin-top: 11px;
        margin-bottom: 22px;
      } h1 {
        line-height:44px;
        margin-top: 11px;
        margin-bottom: 11px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      The Defect Sequence for Contractive Tuples
    </h1>
    <p>
      Tirthankar Bhattacharyya, Bata Krishna Das, Santanu Sarkar
    </p>
    <p>
      We introduce the defect sequence for a contractive tuple of
      Hilbert space operators and investigate its properties. The defect
      sequence is a sequence of numbers, called defect dimensions
      associated with a contractive tuple. We show that there are upper
      bounds for the defect dimensions. The tuples for which these upper
      bounds are obtained, are called maximal contractive tuples. The
      upper bounds are different in the non-commutative and in the
      commutative case. We show that the creation operators on the full
      Fock space and the co ordinate multipliers on the Drury-Arveson
      space are maximal. We also study pure tuples and see how the
      defect dimensions play a role in their irreducibility.
    </p>
    <h2>
      Introduction
    </h2>
    <p>
      Let us fix a positive integer
      <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
        <mi>d</mi>
      </math>
      for this paper. Consider a tuple 
      <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
        <list>
          <ci>
            <msub>
              <mi>T</mi>
              <mn>1</mn>
            </msub>
          </ci>
          <ci>&hellip;</ci>
          <ci>
            <msub>
              <mi>T</mi>
              <mi>d</mi>
            </msub>
          </ci>
        </list>
      </math>
      of bounded operators on a complex, separable, infinite dimensional
      Hilbert Space
      <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
        <mi>H</mi>
      </math>
      and the completely positive map
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Notice how in the paragraph containing the subscripted expression, the first line is correctly displayed, but the presence of the subscript pushes the line height. Is there a for inline math not to push the surrounding text?

Comment: The rendering and its effect on surrounding text is entirely dependent on the browser's MathML implementation and fonts used. You give no indication of which browser or font setup you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Even though nobody responded, I ended up finding a solution to this problem. I guess my question wasn't desirable to this audience. Nonetheless, I am answering it for future reference.

If you want good typography and MathML, use MathJax's MathML mode and its inline command. Inline MathJax is designed to not disrupt line height of a page.